# Multiple row fetch with a cursor in T-SQL on Sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am trying to fetch blocks of rows from my Sybase DB (ie. fetch 100 rows at a time per transaction).

However, I have read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172595%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187881%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that T-SQL simply does not support this.

Is there any work around for this?

Also, if it is possible to fetch multiple rows at a time, how could I modify the following code to do so:

```
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        COL1,
        COL2,
        ...
        COLN
    FROM
        MY_DB
    WHERE
        SOME_CONDITION_SATISFIED
GO

DECLARE
  VAR1 TYPE,
  VAR2 TYPE,
  ...
  VARN TYPE

    SET NO COUNT ON

    OPEN my_cursor
    WHILE @@SQLSTATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH my_cursor into
            @VAR1,
            @VAR2,
            ...
            @VARN
    END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE CURSOR my_cursor
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the database programmer, SQL Server treats cursors just like Sybase and there's nothing wrong with your code. In T-SQL you basically don't have control on the pace the server fetches physical rows to populate the cursor. To the programmer point of view it shouldn't matter though.

If you need this fine grained control over the network usage, you'd better use other APIs better suited for ETL process, such as SSIS.

If your problem is to prevent database contention because of an open transaction, though, you can use `transaction isollation level read uncommitted` (not to lock the table) or insert some transaction management logic with a counter, as:

```
....
DECLARE @counter INT; SET @counter = 0;
BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- OPEN THE FIRST TRANSACTION
OPEN my_cursor
WHILE @@SQLSTATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- control transactions: commit at every 100 and opens another transaction
    IF @counter > 99
    BEGIN
        SET @counter = 0;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END
    ELSE SET @counter = @counter +1;

    FETCH my_cursor into
        @VAR1,
        @VAR2,
        ...
        @VARN
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- CLOSE THE LAST TRANSACTION
....
```

Comment: In your `IF` statement check, why do you have `COMMIT TRANSACTION` followed immediately by `BEGIN TRANSACTION`? Is it so you can follow up with the `FETCH` statement?

Comment: This whole block exists to prevent one single transaction to become too big (with impacts on transaction log and data access contingency issues).

Comment: I was doing some testing with the code and an error occurred. Now my `@@SQLSTATUS` is stuck with a value of `2`..do you know how I can get rid of this?

Comment: `@@SQLSTATUS` returns 2 when there's no more data in the result set, indicating that all rows have already been processed:  [http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/41444;pt=42083]

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch multiple rows at time in sybase. use below to fetch 100 rows at a time

```
set cursor rows 100 for cursor_name
```